# jQuery: onClick swap div positions and change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs (one big and another small). There is a button in a smaller div. `onClick` of a button in the smaller div, I want the divs to swap its positions, in other words, the bigger div becomes small and smaller big becomes large. I am able to achieve that but I am not able to move the button to smaller div after the swap.

*Before swap*
[image]

*After swap*
[image]

**Note**: I want the button in the bottom right corner of Main Panel to be removed and moved to the bottom right corner of Positions Panel.

*Main Panel*

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom" id="mainPanel">
    <!-- Tabs within a box -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab">Area</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sales-chart" data-toggle="tab">Donut</a></li>
        <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Main Panel</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content no-padding">
        <!-- Morris chart - Sales -->
        <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
        <div class="chart tab-pane" id="sales-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
        <li>
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right click-me" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Positions Panel*

```
<div class="box box-solid bg-light-blue-gradient" id="positionsPanel">
    <div class="box-header">
        <!-- tools box -->
        <div class="pull-right box-tools">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm daterange pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Date range">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse" style="margin-right: 5px;">
            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
        <!-- /. tools -->
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
        <h3 class="box-title">
        Positions Panel
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div id="world-map" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body-->
    <div class="box-footer no-border">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4">
                <div id="sparkline-1"></div>
                <div class="knob-label">Visitors</div>
            </div>
            <!-- ./col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4">
                <div id="sparkline-2"></div>
                <div class="knob-label">Online</div>
            </div>
            <!-- ./col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <div id="sparkline-3"></div>
                <div class="knob-label">Exists</div>
            </div>
            <!-- ./col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What I tried so far:

```
// Making function calls
$(".click-me").click(function () {
    // $(this).removeClass('.click-me');
    $('#positionsPanel').addClass('.click-me');
    $("#mainPanel").swap($("#positionsPanel"));
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why move it? Just put a button in each div and hide the one in the big div.

Comment: You want to move the whole nav or just the button? And where you want to put them?

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Let me try that.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir just the button. I want to have a button in the bottom right corner of the smaller div, not in the bigger div.

Comment: @SuhasSrivatsSubburathinam You could swap the div positioning with jQuery like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/s80h1ozk/2/

Comment: @JoshSpears thanks very much. As mentioned, I am able to swap the two divs but I am not able to move the button from one div to another after swapping.

Comment: @SuhasSrivatsSubburathinam Like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/s80h1ozk/3/

Comment: @JoshSpears almost like that. But I always want that button to be in the bottom right corner of the right div (or the smaller div). After the swap, I don't want any button on the bigger div. (See my after swap image minus the button in bigger div but move the button to smaller div.)